# Pandas Replace from Right Only

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'Last, First':['Jim Jrower','Chauncy Peppertooth, Jr']})
               Last, First
0               Jim Jrower
1  Chauncy Peppertooth, Jr
```

I want to delete "Jr" if it occurs on the right side of the string only and not in the middle.

I can't use 
`d['Last, First'].str.rstrip("Jr")`

because that will strip all instances of "J" and "r" from the right.

I can't use

```
d['Last, First'].str.replace("Jr","")
```

because that will take "Jr" out if it occurs in the middle of the string. 
If I can just get rid of that pesky "Jr" at the end, I can then do
 `d['Last, First'].str.rstrip(", ")` to take care of the comma at the end.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `str.replace` with regex

```
d.iloc[:, 0].str.replace(', Jr$', '')
#                             |
#        matches end of line /

0             Jim Jrower
1    Chauncy Peppertooth
Name: Last, First, dtype: object
```

Comment: Could I also do .str.replace(', Jr$|JR$', '') to account for Jr and JR?

Comment: I just verified that I can, but not working in my actual situation for some reason. I'll post another question if it's something of note. Thanks!

Comment: use `d.iloc[:, 0].str.replace(', J[rR]$', '')`

Comment: Still not working on my side. I must be doing something obviously wrong but can't see it. I'm using a column name instead of .iloc[:,0] because I have >1 column and only want to apply it to that column. I'm assuming that wouldn't matter, though. No?

Comment: Could be spaces at the end of the string.   `d.iloc[:, 0].str.replace(', J[rR]\s*$', '')`

Comment: I know I'm pushing it, but what if it were the prefix "Mr " to replace? Would it just be .str.replace(',$M[rR]\s*', '')?

Comment: Nevermind, I did a little digging into Regex and found ^ as the beginning of string marker.  So I just used: .str.replace('^MRS.|^MR.|^MS.|^MISS.|^MRS |^MR |^MS |^MISS ','')

Answer (score 1):

Using the regular expressions module, you can do something like the following

An example:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def example(somestring):
    temp = somestring.lower()
    result = re.search(r'\sjr$', temp)
    if result:
        return somestring[:result.start()]
    else:
        return somestring


d = pd.DataFrame({'Last, First':['Jim Jrower','Chauncy Peppertooth, Jr', 'jonathan jrureiagh, jr']})

d
Out[58]: 
            Last, First
0               Jim Jrower
1  Chauncy Peppertooth, Jr
2   jonathan jrureiagh, jr

d.applymap(example)
Out[59]: 
            Last, First
0            Jim Jrower
1  Chauncy Peppertooth,
2   jonathan jrureiagh,
```